# Linux RegEx Grep Repeat character from n to m times

Tags: grep

I have a problem with this Linux command:

> ls | grep -E 'i{2,3}'

.It should take a file that has at least 2 `i` and max 3 `i`, but it doesn't work.

This is the output

ls:

> life.py, viiva.txt, viiiiiiiiiva.txt

grep:

> viiva.txt, viiiiiiiiiva.txt (with the first 3 I highlighted)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: do you want all `i`'s together or just the count of `i`'s should be between 2 and 3?

Comment: the count of i should be between 2 and 3. I want to see only the file marked as: viiva.txt

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue with OP's attempt** `grep -E 'i{2,3}'` will match two or three consecutive occurrences of `i` anywhere in the input, so 4 or more consecutive `i` is also a valid match.

Parsing `ls` output is not recommended, see [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). If you wish to pass the filenames after filtering to some other command, `find` is a good option.

```
$ ls
1i2i3i.txt  aibi.txt  II.txt  life.py  viiiiiiiiiva.txt  viiva.txt

$ # files with 2 or 3 consecutive i
$ # note that the regex will act on entire filename, thus anchors are not needed
$ find -type f -regextype egrep -regex '[^i]*i{2,3}[^i]*'
./viiva.txt

$ # files with 2 or 3 i anywhere in the name
$ find -type f -regextype egrep -regex '[^i]*i[^i]*i[^i]*(i[^i]*)?'
./aibi.txt
./1i2i3i.txt
./viiva.txt

$ # files with 2 or 3 i anywhere in the name, ignoring case
$ find -type f -regextype egrep -iregex '[^i]*i[^i]*i[^i]*(i[^i]*)?'
./II.txt
./aibi.txt
./1i2i3i.txt
./viiva.txt
```

If filenames won't cause an issue, you can `grep -xE` or `grep -ixE` with above regex, where `x` option will make sure the regex matches the whole line, instead of anywhere in the line. Or you can also use `awk`:

```
$ # NF will give number of fields after splitting on i
$ ls | awk -F'i' 'NF>=3 && NF<=4'
1i2i3i.txt
aibi.txt
viiva.txt

$ ls | awk -F'[iI]' 'NF>=3 && NF<=4'
1i2i3i.txt
aibi.txt
II.txt
viiva.txt
```